# :class not updating when clicked in vuejs v-for

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I want to add a css class to a item in v-for when the td in clicked

```
      <template>
  <div>
    <h1>Forces ()</h1>

    <section v-if="errored">
      <p>We're sorry, we're not able to retrieve this information at the moment, please try back later</p>
    </section>

    <section v-if="loading">
      <p>loading...</p>
    </section>

    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>ID</th>

          <th 
              @click="orderByName = !orderByName">Forces</th>
        </tr>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(force, index) in forces" @click="completeTask(force)" :class="{completed: force.done}"  v-bind:key="index">

          <td>
            <router-link :to="{ name: 'ListForce', params: { name: force.id } }">Link</router-link>
          </td>

          <th>{{ force.done }}</th>

          <th>{{ force.name }}</th>
          <th><button v-on:click="removeElement(index)">remove</button></th>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>


<script>
import {APIService} from '../APIService';
const apiService = new APIService();
const _ = require('lodash');

export default {

  name: 'ListForces',

  components: {

  },

  data() {
    return {
      question: '',
      forces: [{
        done: null,
        id: null,
        name: null
      }],
      errored: false,
      loading: true,
      orderByName: false,
    };

  },

  methods: {
    getForces(){
      apiService.getForces().then((data, error) => {

          this.forces = data;
          this.forces.map(function(e){
               e.done = false;
          });
          this.loading= false;
        console.log(this.forces)
      });
    },
    completeTask(force) {
      force.done = ! force.done;
      console.log(force.done);
    },
    removeElement: function (index) {
      this.forces.splice(index, 1);
    }
  },

  computed: {
/*    forcesOrdered() {
      return this.orderByName ? _.orderBy(this.forces, 'name', 'desc') : this.forces;
    }*/
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getForces();
  },
}
</script>

<style>
    .completed {
        text-decoration: line-through;
    }
</style>
```

I want a line to go through the items when clicked, but the dom doesn't update. If I go into the vue tab in chrome I can see the force.done changes for each item but only if I click out of the object and click back into it. I'm not to sure why the state isn't updating as it's done so when I have used an click and a css bind before.

Comment: It sounds like a reactivity problem. Where is `forcesOrdered` coming from? Is it defined somewhere in component `data` or store `state`? You might like to try using `this.$set(force, 'done', true)` to see whether that works. It doesn't address the underlying problem but it would help to confirm that it's a reactivity problem.

Comment: Is `done` an existing property on these objects or are you adding it in `completeTask`?

Comment: Hi, yes it's a property in the object

Comment: forcesOrdered is in computed

Comment: tried the this.$set(force, 'done', true) but the same as before, the value is updated but not updated on screen

Comment: Could you include the code for the computed property `forcesOrdered`? You shouldn't be modifying the value returned from a computed property directly but without seeing the code it's difficult to make a concrete suggestion.

Comment: Hi, I've switched it back to the data directly now so 'force in forces', but still having trouble. The code for the order thing though was: /* forcesOrdered() {
      return this.orderByName ? _.orderBy(this.forces, 'name', 'desc') : this.forces;
    } */

Comment: I've added the whole component so hopefully makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to make minimal changes to get this working:

```js
// import {APIService} from '../APIService';
// const apiService = new APIService();
// const _ = require('lodash');

const apiService = {
  getForces () {
    return Promise.resolve([
      { id: 1, name: 'Red' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Green' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Blue' }
    ])
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  name: 'ListForces',

  components: {

  },

  data() {
    return {
      question: '',
      forces: [{
        done: null,
        id: null,
        name: null
      }],
      errored: false,
      loading: true,
      orderByName: false,
    };

  },

  methods: {
    getForces(){
      apiService.getForces().then((data, error) => {
          for (const force of data) {
            force.done = false;
          }

          this.forces = data;
          this.loading= false;
        console.log(this.forces)
      });
    },
    completeTask(force) {
      force.done = ! force.done;
      console.log(force.done);
    },
    removeElement: function (index) {
      this.forces.splice(index, 1);
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getForces();
  }
})
```

```css
.completed {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <h1>Forces ()</h1>

    <section v-if="errored">
      <p>We're sorry, we're not able to retrieve this information at the moment, please try back later</p>
    </section>

    <section v-if="loading">
      <p>loading...</p>
    </section>

    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>ID</th>

          <th 
              @click="orderByName = !orderByName">Forces</th>
          <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(force, index) in forces" @click="completeTask(force)" :class="{completed: force.done}"  v-bind:key="index">

          <th>{{ force.done }}</th>

          <th>{{ force.name }}</th>
          <th><button v-on:click="removeElement(index)">remove</button></th>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The key problem was here:

```js
this.forces = data;
this.forces.map(function(e){
  e.done = false;
});
```

The problem here is that the property `done` is being added to the data after it has been made reactive. The reactivity observers get added as soon as the line `this.forces = data` runs. Adding `done` after that counts as adding a new property, which won't work.

It's also a misuse of `map` so I've switched it to a `for`/`of` loop instead.

```js
for (const force of data) {
  force.done = false;
}

this.forces = data; // <- data becomes reactive here, including 'done'
```

On an unrelated note I've tweaked the template to move the `Delete` header inside the top row.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `force.done` is set to `false` in `data` before initialization so it is reactive.

```
data() {
  return {
    force:{
      done: false;
    }
  }
}
```

If `force` exists but has no `done` member set, you can use `Vue.set` instead of `=` to create a reactive value after initialization.

```
Vue.set(this.force, 'done', true);
```